# How could I initialize DataTable from Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, metronic

DataTable() removes the @click="editUser(user)" whenever I disable the initializing I get it working. But, once the table is rendered I cannot add the `@click` event. I also tried `v-on:click`

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-icon" @click="onClick(user)"><i class="la la-edit"></i></button>`

Comment: Where is `DataTable()` coming from? Is it a plugin?

Comment: yeah a metronic plugin that initializes DataTable

Comment: Shameless plug, if you're referring to datatables.net/jQuery DataTables then my plugin may be of help: https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net